# remove special character from phone number and compare

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table structure:

```
|id  |Phone_number         
|98  |+91 9033601870
|208 |+44 6547891235
|227 |+93 35465465
|229 |+1 9033601870
|259 |+1 9033601870
|374 |+ 1 97 2- 71 4- 01 17
|375 |+1 972-714-0117
|376 |+92 97271 40117
|444 |+1 888-888-8888
|445 |+1 441-562-3124
|446 |9727140117
```

**Now i want all the result which has number `9727140117`**

I have tried below things.

```
SELECT acp.*
FROM `acd_contactlist_phone` acp
WHERE acp.Phone_number like '%9727140117%';
```

This query give me wrong results.This query give me only last record.

My Expected result is:

```
 |id  |Phone_number   
 |374 |+ 1 97 2- 71 4- 01 17
 |375 |+1 972-714-0117
 |376 |+92 97271 40117
 |446 |9727140117
```

Current Query result is :

```
 |id  |Phone_number   
 |446 |9727140117
```

Comment: I think a better solution would be to clean up all the data before you insert into the database. Then your query would work. You could clean up the existing database entries with simple updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace()`:

```
SELECT acp.*
FROM `acd_contactlist_phone` acp
WHERE replace(replace(replace(acp.number, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') like '%9727140117%';
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have regular expression replace or a `translate()` function.

Another option would be a complex regular expression:

```
where acp.number regexp '9[- +]*7[- +]*2[- +]*7[- +]*1[- +]*4[- +]*0[- +]*1[- +]*1[- +]*7[- +].*'
```

Comment: there are many different special character is available like (),-,+ etc , so for all that i have to use replace?

Comment: @chiragsatapara . . . That is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: that is not possible to make one regex , which is remove all the special character and give only numbers ?

Comment: I am using a intelinput for the phone number , so this plugin format the number according to the country which you select.

Comment: @chiragsatapara . . . I already have an alternative solution with a regular expression.  You would need to add more characters between the square brackets.

Comment: can you please check the sagar answer  and tell us that thing is possible without using a Function ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you look at my answer and guide us for questioner query ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create one simple function which removes all special characters and alphabet from your String as shown below.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS onlynum; 
    DELIMITER | 
    CREATE FUNCTION onlynum( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(16) 
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
      DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
      DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
      SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
      REPEAT 
        BEGIN 
          SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
          IF c REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' THEN 
            SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
          END IF; 
          SET i = i + 1; 
        END; 
      UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
      RETURN ret; 
    END | 
    DELIMITER ; 
    ;
```

And then execute below query.

```
SELECT acp.*
FROM `acd_contactlist_phone` acp
WHERE onlynum(acp.number) like '%9727140117%';
```

Try above code.

Comment: this thing is possible without using function ? direct using regex?

Comment: As you have to iterate it's not possible to direct using `regex`. Still @gordon had best way to resolve issue.So may be he can guide us.

Answer (score 0):

The query is returning correct, it wouldn't consider space/- so it will return all required result, if you reduce the wildcard check to less number of digits.

```
SELECT acp.*
FROM `acd_contactlist_phone` acp
WHERE acp.Phone_number like '%0117%';
```

Answer (score 0):

With ***REGEXP*** operator:

```
SELECT acp.*
FROM `acd_contactlist_phone` acp
WHERE acp.Phone_number REGEXP '9[^0-9]*7[^0-9]*2[^0-9]*7[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*4[^0-9]*0[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*7';
```

Comment: there is not possible to make one regex , which is remove all the special character and give only numbers like regex(acp.phone_number) like `9727140117`

Comment: @chiragsatapara, what do you asking? your expected result do contain special characters. This solution gives the expected result

Comment: yes my expected result contain special character but  i am asking to remove  in where condition and compare with number.